# How to associate .js files with Nodejs on Linux?

Tags: linux, node.js

How to associate javascript files with Node on Linux? I want to run js script i.e. "mainnet.js" without typing "node mainnet.js", see below

```
$ mainnet.js
exec: "mainnet.js": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I'm using Ubuntu

Comment: Add shebang, make file executable call it with `./mainnet.js`. But i would just type out node

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` definition?

Comment: Yes I do have package.json, but it is already used to start server ..

Comment: I added shebang '#!/usr/local/bin/env node' to mainnet.js and verified node is in directory  /usr/local/bin/ also gave executable to mainnet.js says bash: ./dping.js: /usr/local/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Try creating a new script in the`scripts`  section  of `package.json` eg.: `"command": "node mainnet.js"`. Then run the script with npm: `npm run command`.